# What is the difference between screw and wrench in rigid body motion?

Tags: dynamics, theory, screw-theory

A screw is defined by a six dimensional vector of forces and torques. It can represent any spatial movement of a rigid body ([as written here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory#Basic_concepts)). But I don't get the following distinction between screw and wrench:

> The force and torque vectors that arise in applying Newton's laws to a rigid body can be assembled into a screw called a **wrench**.

It seems to be some kind of contextualisation but in what way?

Answer (score 4):

I will try to make it as simple as possible. Imagine you have a SCREW, when you WRENCH it, it TWIST forward or backward.

From your wiki link

> The components of the screw define the Plücker coordinates of a line in space and the magnitudes of the vector along the line and moment about this line.

It means that any system can be described as those coordinate system is a screw. For example a normal screw has it axis and it pitch.

A WRENCH is one case of SCREW where the act (force or torque) have the axis and yield a movement (translation or rotation)

You can have a look at the slide of [the Summer Screw Summer School](http://www.dimec.unige.it/PMAR/summer_screws/SS09/PDF/Part1/SS09-Zlatanov.pdf) for more detail.

Comment: I haven't considered a screw to be a `coordinate system`. My way of thinking was always, that the screw enables a lower dimensional representation of displacement. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: What can be described in a system with an axis and the magnitudes vector along the axis is a SCREW. From the [Summer Screw](http://www.dimec.unige.it/PMAR/summer_screws/SS09/PDF/Part1/SS09-Zlatanov.pdf) page 19 : a line l with a pitch h (a metric quantity) is a geometric element called a screw. A wrench is a system of forces (reduced at a point) with equivalent systems identified.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing from [Murray, Li, and Sastry](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/mlswiki/index.php/Main_Page) (chapters 3 and 5) there are 3 related things:

- Twist: An element of se(3) (which is a bit like the derivative of an element of SE(3), which is the set of translations + rotations)
- Screw: A translation+rotation (i.e. and element of SE(3))
- Wrench: Generalized force (combination of linear force and torque)

Comment: Thanks for the summary, that helps a lot! Could you please explain why it is possible to state a wrench as a combination of force and torque as well as a screw and a force magnitude?

Comment: Sorry, can you restate your question? I don't quite understand.

Comment: I refer to this paper: http://profs.sci.univr.it/~fiorini/corsi/robotica/icra2001notes.pdf page 28, where one can see that a wrench can either be expressed as a concatenation of force and moment or as a convolution of screw and force. For me it is still not clear, why this holds - but maybe this is no longer part of this thread

Comment: Sorry, but without studying it in more detail I'm not sure exactly what that paper is saying. I *think* it is saying that, similar to 3D motion, a wrench can be described by defining a line of action and a scalar times a pitch (i.e. similar to a screw describing a 3D motion).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend a patient lecture of the chapters related to rigid body kinematics and dynamics  of the book by Goldstein: classical mechanics. It will clear all our doubts.